# Typescript: type parent class method with child properties

Tags: typescript

I have this code ([play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggg3gWACgEEATAewGUyBbAUwgAsBLAOwHMAKMkAK1vgBcCAArAoEJsGQAeCAE8ADrTIAzBIyZgAfAEpchYsVhkWYMsloA6ZGU7c+8HQYQBfQm4KEUaDACEEtAAeELQsJBjY+EQICgCMCAC8CADkyc4KAEyJCAAMhM5kjLRQHHpRhurMYJbkVHQa7Bw4cULJwMkuegD0XQjSALQIAKJQUGRQzh4eXiaQCCDZLLQA7gi+pYQgNZQ09MyNzbGt7QA0MRlCGZ0IPX2DAOrjANZgQA)):

```js
abstract class A {
  doSomething(object: Partial<typeof this>) {
    console.log(object)
  }
}

class B extends A {
  p1 = ''
  p2 = 0

  other() {
    this.doSomething({p1: 'a'}) // <- Error
  }
}

const b = new B()
b.doSomething({p1: 'a', p2: 2}) // <- Works
```

Why this does not work inside `other` method? How can i fix it?

Comment: `A` does not know about the existence of `B` as it is the parent. `Partial<typeof this>` therefore does not know about the properties `p1` or `p2`.

Comment: Polymorphism works as expected, the issue is not with that; you can verify that by moving the function `doSomething` from `A` to `B` - the error is still there! It seems to be confused by the type of `this` in `other`. It actually works if you use `(this as B).doSomething({p1: 'a'})`. Another solution would be to declare the type of `this` in `other`: `other(this: B) {...`

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that not only polymorphism works fine, but it's the right justification of this error (similar to [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16356)).

The problem is that `this` may be the type of a class that *extends* `B`, let's call it `C` and for that class `{p1: "a"}` may not fit `Partial<C>`.

Although the first thought may be that if the class `B` has a `p1: string`, the derived classes would also have it. But in fact it is possible for a derived class to have a `p1` of a type that is *narrower* than `string`, for instance a specific string.

In the following example I simplified the code generating the problem, and added an example class `C`:

```ts
class B{
  p1 = ''
  p2 = 0
  
  doSomething(object: Partial<this>) {
    console.log(object)
  }
}

function other<T extends B>(t: T) {
  t.doSomething({p1: 'a'}) // <- error
}

class C extends B{
  p1: 'c' = 'c'
}

const x: Partial<C> = {p1: 'a'}; // not OK
const y: Partial<C> = {p1: 'c'}; // OK
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WGAgvN).

Apart from the "dirty" solutions from the comments, a serious fix would only mean a redesign of the code such that it doesn't use `Partial<this>` - in this context, because of possible future overriding of properties, it really doesn't match anything meaningful.